# MySQL выборка по разным условиям в одном запросе

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!

Что-то никак не могу понять как в за один запрос вытащить из БД данные.

Есть массив с данными

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [val_id] => 1
        [values_id] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [val_id] => 1
        [values_id] => 2
    )
)
```

Есть запрос вида

```
    $query = "
    SELECT 
        field_1, field_2 
    FROM 
        table1 t1, table2 t2 
    WHERE 
        t1.id = '".$id."' AND t1.val_id = '".$val_id."' AND 
        t2.id = t1.id AND 
        t1.values_id = '".$values_id."'
";
```

Сейчас скрипт проходит по массиву. Что очень не удобно. Так как в списке может быть много инфы, соответственно, запросов выходит очень много.

Возвращает сейчас такой массив

```
Array
(
    [field_1] => 0.0000
    [field_2 ] => 0
)
```

Что тут можно сделать, чтобы запрос был один и возвращало многомерный массив такого вида?

```
Array
(
    [тут id] => Array
    (
        [field_1] => 2.0000
        [field_2 ] => 0
    )
    [тут id] => Array
    (
        [field_1] => 1.0000
        [field_2 ] => 0
    )
)
```

Буду благодарен за помощь и советы.

Comment: @drop_off, не очень понятно из какой таблицы у вас выбираются поля field_1 и field_2... тут eav или что-то свое придуманное?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, забыл проставить таблицу. да.
но не особо важно. там выборка из t2 идет.

Comment: в таком случае t1 у вас лишняя таблица:

    select field_1, field_2
    from table2
    where id = $id

или вы что-то неверно написали, или id у вас не ключ, или...
ЗЫ sql не возвращает многомерные массивы, если вы об этом. только плоские таблицы, перебираете записи и формируете многомерные массивы сами...

Comment: не не. нужна. там еще некоторые данные берутся. просто лишним забивать не стал пример.

Comment: id у вас в обеих таблицах первичный ключ? или опять что-то "лишнее" опустили?  
ладно, если запросы у вас одинаковые, а меняются только три эти условия, то соедините эти запросы через union all, т.е.

    select field_1, field_2 from ...
    union all
    select field_1, field_2 from ...
    ...

запрос будет один. но вообще вы что-то делаете не так, структура странная какая-то данные выбираете непонятные. хотя может быть это только для меня...

Comment: Да, id первичный ключ и там и там. Запросы получаются одинаковые, меняются только три условия.


структура такая в древнем, самописном движке, который жутко тормозит. почему и пытаюсь изменить кое-что.

Comment: тогда зачем нужны условия values_id и по val_id?  

    SELECT 
        field_1, field_2 
    FROM 
        table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
    WHERE 
        t1.id in (1,2,3,4,5);

Answer (score 1):

ну сначала перебери цикл и сформируй строку. Типо:

```
$sql_id += " OR t1.id = '".$id."'"
```

далее думаю сам додумаешь.

Comment: @Илья Чижанов, там выборка по трем условиям. Это если у меня список из 30 записей, то 30 условий в итоге будет?

Comment: да. и ещё для оптимизации лучше всего не трогать повторяющиеся. то есть если взять массив из вашего примера будет примерно такой запрос.
    SELECT 
        field_1, field_2 
    FROM 
        table1 t1, table2 t2 
    WHERE 
        t1.id = '1' AND t1.val_id = '1' AND 
        t2.id = t1.id AND 
        t1.values_id = '1' or t1.values_id = '2'

Comment: [expr IN (value,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, каким образом IN тут реализовать?

Comment: @drop_off, ну вместо or можно использовать in...

Comment: Буду пробовать. Пока что-то не выходит.